# ActiveRecord::Base attributes doesn't work when enclosed in find()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm inside my edit.html.erb view, rendering _form.html.erb partial.

The code below, on its own, would output the integer '5'

```
<%= ff.object.product_id %>
```

but the moment I enclose it inside a find function, it outputs an error: 
Couldn't find Product without an ID

```
<%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(ff.object.product_id).name %>
```

If I hardcode the integer, it will work

```
<%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(5).name %>
```

How do I get ff.object.product_id to work inside find()?

---

```
<%= form.nested_fields_for :purchase_order_items, wrapper_tag: :tr do |ff| %>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <div class="input-product_code-div">
          <%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(ff.object.product_id).code %>
        </div>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :product_id, class: "input-product_code" %>
      </td>
      <td>               
        <div class="input-product_name-div">            
          <%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : '' %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <%=  ff.number_field :quantity, :step => "0.01", class: "form-control input-quantity" %>        
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <%=  ff.number_field :unit_price, :step => "0.01",class: "form-control input-unit_price" %>
      </td>  
      <td>
        <div class="input-currency-div"></div>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :currency, class: "input-currency" %>
      </td>  
      <td align="center">
        <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link "", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash input-remove-row', role: 'button' %>
      </td> 
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `ff.object.product_id`. May be it is `nil`. May be you got it deleted.

Comment: it outputs the integer: 5. I also checked ff.object.product_id.class and it is indeed an integer

Comment: `@products` will not be having the `Product` with id 5. The query to populate `@products` might be leaving it out or you have deleted the record. If you have the product in the database, then you will have to look in to how `@products` is populated.

Comment: @product.find(5) outputs an object. If i hardcode the integer, it will find the object.

Comment: I don't see how it can happen :D  can you give the rest of the view. Including where `ff` is set.

Comment: I'm also confused! I've updated the question with the rest of the form

Comment: If I try @products.find(ff.object.id) it detects the integer, but that's not the id I need. :(

Comment: is it a partial? are you calling this partial in a loop ?? If yes, it might happen that for first iteration it returns `5` but in other iteration the value is `nil`

Comment: @Salil Nope, if i just output ff.object.product_id, the loop will display the correct integer per iteration.

Comment: above your hardcode,`<%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(5).code %>`, add a line `<%= ff.object.product_id %>`. Does it show '5' everytime your partial is rendered, or they are different numbers/ids?

Comment: @kiddorails different numbers, I am sure of the way ff.object.product_id is looped. It just doesn't seem to work when inside find(). I do want to note that all the other attributes of ff.object is being recognized. (ex. @products.find(ff.object.purchase_order_id) detects the integer, @products.find(ff.object.unit_price) detects the integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below line of code,

```
<%= @purchase_order.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(ff.object.product_id).name %>
```

You are checking if `@purchase_order` is new record or not that's okay.

But you are not checking if `ff.object` is new record or not?

It can be possible that ff.object is new record and it does not have `product_id` column filled which is giving you error.

I think you should write it as

```
<%= ff.object.new_record? ? '' : @products.find(ff.object.product_id).name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I agreed with @Amulya might be ff.object could be new record.

But instead of using find query to all products ,you could replace it with

```
<%= ff.object.product.try(:name) %>
```